# Trouble logging Active Directory from Windows Server 2022 to an Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS

Tags: permissions, 22.04, login, users, active-directory

I actually joined the realm, but the problem is when I try to log in with an *Active Directory* user, I can't. I added the machine to the active directory via installation and everything is ok.

running realm list:

```
AAA@grup2-ud1:~$ sudo realm list
 
grup2.ZZZ.ZZZ   
  type: kerberos  
  realm-name: GRUP2.ZZZ.ZZZ  
  domain-name: grup2.ZZZ.ZZZ   
  configured: kerberos-member  
  server-software: active-directory  
  client-software: sssd  
  required-package: sssd-tools  
  required-package: sssd  
  required-package: libnss-sss  
  required-package: libpam-sss  
  required-package: adcli  
  required-package: samba-common-bin  
  login-formats: %U@grup2.ZZZ.ZZZ   
  login-policy: allow-realm-logins
```

I tried logging with user interface and also executing `sudo login` but I can't log in with the *Administrator* user of the Active Directory.

- I need to configure something like Kerberos or something?
- I may be missing some configuration?

The windows Active Directory maybe is not the issue because I can join the realm and log with the AD users using windows as an OS
I tried [this tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd-ad) from Ubuntu but still nothing.
Hope someone can help me.

PD: Is a school project, so the Windows Server and the Ubuntu Desktop is all created by my own with virtual machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

I finally achieved it!

The troubles I found and solved is the next:

- The hostname needs to have the AD domain: grup2-ud1.[domain AD]
- The package krb5-user needs to be installed and add `rdns=false` in */etc/krb5.conf*. In addition to the packages recommended by the [tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd-ad).

## Resources

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4x_RSvpY6OE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMVMS1vyP18&t=224s
https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/sssd-realm-join.131067/
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd-ad